# Bulk Insertion in MYSQL from XML Files

Tags: mysql, xml, bulkinsert

How can we load data to Mysql Tables from XML Files??
Is there any way to read data from XML Files and Write to MySql database..
I have a bulk of data in XML Files.

Thanks in Advance for help.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/load-xml.html) function (MySQL 6.0). Here's the sample code from the reference manual:

Using an XML document **person.xml** containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
  <person person_id="1" fname="Pekka" lname="Nousiainen"/>
  <person person_id="2" fname="Jonas" lname="Oreland"/>
  <person person_id="3"><fname>Mikael</fname><lname>Ronström</lname></person>
  <person person_id="4"><fname>Lars</fname><lname>Thalmann</lname></person>
  <person><field name="person_id">5</field><field name="fname">Tomas</field><field name="lname">Ulin</field></person>
  <person><field name="person_id">6</field><field name="fname">Martin</field><field name="lname">Sköld</field></person>
</list>
```

you would create a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP
);
```

and use the following command to import the XML:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'person.xml'
INTO TABLE person
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<person>';
```

Or if you're running MySQL 5.0 you can use [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) to load the entire XML document as a string into a single column, and then parse it using MySQL's XPath functionality.

This article on MySQL.com has more details: [Using XML in MySQL 5.1 and 6.0](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html).

Comment: Hi Calvin, I m using 5.1 Version and Have gone through ur Link, there I found the Procedure for Loaing XMLFile Data to MYSql, I have Used , It shows no Error but the Data hasn't been loaded in Table, I used it 2wice of 3rice, It shows now error but Fills nodata on TAble.
Can you help me.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you have into the question; that way we can take a closer look at what you're doing and perhaps figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a simple solution, Navicat has a pretty simple xml import function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use XSL to translate the XML into standard SQL insert statements, then use the "source" command from within the mysql client to read the output?

Comment: might be simpler to use generate CSV instead of SQL from XML, but the general idea is the easiest.