# store object array to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

here's my task. I've parsed an xml document and stored all of its data in an array. The array format is

```
Array(
    [0]=> deals Object(
        [deal_id]=>... 
        [deal_title]=>...
    )
    [1]=> deals Object(
        [deal_id]=>....
        [deal_title]=>...
    )
)
```

what i need to do is to store values for each object in mysql database but not all of the object's tags should be stored in the same datatable.
The reason why i first created the array is that the same php file will parse the xml and then will insert the values in the database OR if an entry with the same deal_id already exists in the database will update the appropriate tables. So I thought that having the xml in an array will help the further checking code. 
If anyone has a different suggestion I'd be glad to hear..

Thanks in advance!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deals>
<deal>
<id>1</id>
<title>title</title>
<city>city<city>
<price>20</price>
<url>http://....</url>
<previous_price>30</previous_price>
<discount> 10</discount>
<image>http://....</image>
<description> description</description>
<purchases> 1</purchases>
<address>address</address>
<latitude>30.5666</latitude>
<longitude>403.6669</longitude>
<start>datetime</start>
<end>datetime</end>
<active>true</active>
<category>category</category>
<type>type</type>
</deal>
</deals>
```

that's the xml file structure

Comment: how about `insert ... on duplicate key update`. More here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: For your described scenario its not necessary to turn the xml into an array first. In fact, since it's easy to iterate XML contents, it's superfluous to do so in most scenarios. Just update/insert while traversing the DOM tree.

Comment: @Gordon so your suggestion is to pass directy from xml to database??I'm not any close to php or mysql expert so my problem with iretation through xml contents was how in the foreach statement i could ask the database if the deal_id field already exists..

Comment: @kate actually, it's the same you'd be doing it with your array. Can you provide an example of your XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
foreach ($array as $deal) {
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($deal['deal_title']);
    $id = int($deal['deal_id']);
    if ($id) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO deals (id, title) VALUES ($id, '$title') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE deals SET title = '$title' WHERE id = $id";
        mysql_query($query);
    } else {
        echo "ID is not a valid integer.";
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt be using [ext/mysql](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) anymore. Use [PDO](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to insert from the XML directly using [PDO](http://bd.php.net/pdo) and [Prepared Statements](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements):

```
$deals = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($deals->deal as $deal) {
    // assuming you created a $pdo object before
    $pdo->prepare(
        'INSERT 
            INTO deals (id, title, …, type) 
            VALUES (:id, :title, …, :type) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                UPDATE deals 
                SET title = :title, …, type = :type 
                WHERE id = :id
        ');
    $pdo->execute(
        array(
            ':id'    => (string) $deal->id,    
            ':title' => (string) $deal->title,
            …
            ':type' => (string) $deal->type,
        )
    );
}
```

Note that this will create one Query for each $deal in the XML. A more practical and performant approach is described in

- [Bulk Insertion in MYSQL from XML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721645/bulk-insertion-in-mysql-from-xml-files)