# PHP split array in hundreds

Tags: php

I have an array that can hold up to several thousands of items.(usually around 5000 items).
I need to split this array into hundreds and process them and then continue with the rest of items.
So far i handle the whole array which is slow. 
My code is

```
foreach($result as $p){
                $sqlQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message_details(contact, message_id)VALUES('$p', $message_last_id)");
                $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
                $xmlString .= "<gsm messageId=\"$last_id\">".$p."</gsm>";
                $cnt++;
            }
```

How can i process the items in the array in hundreds? Eg. 100, then 200, then 300 etc

Best Regards,
Nicos

Comment: Why not use `sleep()` and let SQL server recover (or whatever)? Also update XML file on each iteration.

Comment: Why would processing chunks of a hundred items be any better?

Comment: The bottle neck might actually be the insert itself. I'd start with inserting multiple rows at once, using the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (row1), (row2), ...` syntax. Locking the table, you can derive the id manually, it being the last one plus one.

Comment: I'm not a pro but I do feel like if you split the array like $_array[x][I] it will work better. This way you can split the array into more categories etc. But this will not speed it up it might even slow it down even more

Comment: @Nicos In .Net when I've needed to do bulk insertion I've always created an xml document from all the objects I need to insert then sent that to a stored proc.  This is also possible with PHP and MySQL but I have no examples.  There's a SO post on MySQL bulk insertion with xml here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721645/bulk-insertion-in-mysql-from-xml-files and the PHP docs tell you how to create XML documents.  That'll probably be the fastest way but you'll spend a bit of time implementing it I should imagine.

Comment: Well, first of all thanks for all the replies. Second, its not about inserting in Mysql the problem. Yes, my way of 1 insert in each loop is way wrong, so thank you for all the suggestions. What i really want to do, is to send that xml to a remote server that can accept around 100 lines of xml each time. that's why i want to split the array in 100's

Comment: @Nicos in that case see my answer regarding chunking an array in PHP.  It's the one at the bottom with 0 votes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **have** to do it in the code the you can use the php function array_chunk to chunk your array into arrays of 100 elements each.  Here's the docs on array_chunk: [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).  But as pointed out this is unlikely to be the bottle neck.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed.

$chunk_result = array_chunk($result, 150, true);
foreach($chunk_result as $chunk)
{
   //code here
   foreach ($chunk as $p)
   {
     //code here
   }
}

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you might try it that way:

First select the last ID of message_details.

```
$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT %last_id_col_name% FROM message_details ORDER BY %last_id_col_name% DESC LIMIT 1".$sInserts);
```

then:

```
$sInserts = '';

foreach($result as $p){
    $sInserts .= "('{$p}', {$message_last_id}),";
}

//Remove last "," from Insert-String
$sInserts = substr($sInserts,0,-1);

//Insert all with one query
$sqlQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message_details(contact, message_id)VALUES".$sInserts);
```

then select all entries from that table, where id is greater than the one you've selected first
and write to

```
$xmlString .= '<gsm messageId="'.$last_id.'">'.$p.'</gsm>';
```

If you are doing it that way, you only need 3 DB-Queries, instead of thousands.

Comment: Auto-increment does take care of the ids, no need to enter own ids into the insert query. Also, the string concatenation looks terrible. I'd go with passing an array to pdo or something higher level.

Comment: I've only adapted his insert. I don't know if `$message_last_id` means the id of that table. What I wanted to show is, that it's not necessary to make an insert, every each-loop. This is the reason, why the script takes that long.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($result as $p){
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message_details(contact, message_id)VALUES('$p', $message_last_id)");
    $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    $xmlString .= "<gsm messageId=\"$last_id\">".$p."</gsm>";
    $cnt++;

   if ($cnt % 1000 == 0) { usleep(100) }
}
```

You can use `usleep` or `sleep` depending on what you want. I've already used this. You gain performance. Try it.

Comment: Does this only prevent database buffer to overflow and to swap data to hdd? Might be it has further implications I cannot see.

Comment: @MikulasDite If you have a lot of data to insert on database or you buffer the SGDB or you overflow you app memory. One way will be affected in a way or another. This method I posted holds this execution on app machine, not on SGDB.

Comment: Well it does not really prevent php memory overflow as the garbage collector is certainly not trashing array rows iterated. Though I agree it should improve the performance in a way. Not sure to what degree it might go though.