# php loop 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, mysql, loops, memory-limit

Good afternoon.

I have a problem with php `foreach` loop.

I parse xml file ( ~20mb ) using *simplexml* and then insert data to *mysql*

in xml are over 37000 items,i must loop 37000 times ,to read data from xml

every 100 iteration i create string like this:
`insert into my_table values (...)`

But i get a 502 error in 10500-st iteration.

I try send string after loop,but get error again:

```
memory_limit=240 
max_execution_time 500
```

How can I solve this problem.
Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Have you considered using MySQL Bulk insert, which can pull directly from an XML file?  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/721812/138200)

Comment: yes, xml's structure are bad
example
<item param1='val' param2='val2'><param3>val3</param3>... </item>

Comment: why is that bad?  Use XSLT to transform it to match the destination table format.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your script is timing out, you can overcome this by using `set_time_limit(0)` in you script or by changing the `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini`:

```
while(1) {
  set_time_limit(0);
  // do something
}
```

You also need to increase your `memory_limit` by editing your `php.ini` and restart your webserver.

Read documentation for [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: script executing long, yes,but I think the problem is that the server thinks it's a infinite loop.
and i can't use mysql command "load from file" because xml's structure are bad

Comment: @Kandrat - Are you running nginx or apache?

Answer (score 0):

### Can you split the one big xml into several smaller files?

I'd queue the 37000 items into several batches and process them one after another or asynchronous. I've done this a few times in PHP. A better language for jobs like this would be Phyton or RoR.

**However, try creating batches of the items.**

### Regarding storing the data, I use CSV batch inserts with MySQL.

I use this function to convert the strings into CSV format:

```
<?php
function convertStrToCsv($data, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"')
{
    ob_start();
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, $data, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    fclose($fp);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

… then I save the functions output as a file and finaly use this query to save the CSV data in the Database:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE '$file' IGNORE INTO TABLE `$table` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';
```

### Read more about this:

- [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
- [PHP's str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Happy coding!

Comment: your method is good ,but to convert xml to valid format(if not mysql return error)
i must loop all xml ,and then execute mysql query
but in loop i get error(

Comment: You could try to load the xml partially. Have a look at the _less memory consuming_ and quite _fast_ SAX based [**XML Parser**](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parser-create.php). You can find **an example** of this parser in use [**here**](http://www.codemiles.com/php-tutorials/php-sax-parser-in-action-t1436.html). **An alternative** to the XML Parser is the [**XML Reader**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) which is _easier to implement_ but uses _more memory_ and _performs slower_.