# Loading large XML file from url into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need to load XML data from an external server/url into my MySQL database, using PHP.
I don't need to save the XML file itself anywhere, unless this is easier/faster.

The problem is, I will need this to run every hour or so as the data will be constantly updated, therefore I need to replace the data in my database too. The XML file is usually around 350mb.

The data in the MySQL table needs to be searchable - I will know the structure of the XML so can create the table to suit first.

I guess there are a few parts to this question:

1. What's the best way to automate this whole process to run every hour?
2. Whats the best(fastest?) way of downloading/ parsing the xml (~350mb) from the url? in a way that I can -
3. load it into a mysql table of my own, maintaining columns/ structure

Comment: check out this stack post I think it may have what u are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/721645/1975259

Comment: 1. cron, 2,3 LOAD_FILE

Comment: Loading a xml file : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

1) A PHP script can keep running in background all the time, but this is not the best scenario or you can set a `php -q /dir/to/php.php` using cronos (if running on linux) or other techniques to makes server help you. (You still need access to server)

2) You can use several systems, the more linear one, less RAM consuming, is if you decide to work with files or with a modified mySQL access is opening your TCP connection, streaming smaller packages (16KB will be ok) and streaming them out on disk or another connection.

3) Moving so huge data is not difficult, but storing them in mySQL is not waste. Performing search in it is even worst. Updating it is trying to kill mySQL system.

Suggestions:
From what i can see, you are trying to synchronize or back-up data from another server. If there is just one file then make a local `.xml` using PHP and you are done. If there are more than one i will still suggest to make local files as most probably you are working with unstructured data: they are not for mySQL. If you work with hundreds of files and you need to search them fast perform statistics and much much more... consider to change approach and read about hadoop.

MySQL BLOOB or TEXT columns still not support more than 65KB, maybe you know another technique, but i never heard about it and I will never suggest to do so. If you are trying it just to use SQL SEARCH commands you took the wrong path.